# How to allocate resources per website basis on Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, hosting, lamp, web

I have Ubuntu LAMP Server with Webmin. I want to limit the disk space/RAM usage and CPU usage per site basis. For example I want to allocate 5GB disk space and 50GB Bandwidth to site1.com and 10GB Disk space and 100GB Bandwidth to site2.com

How to do this? Can we do this using .htaccess? Is there any open source solution available?

Comment: Is there any way to measure the disk space usage and bandwidth of any particular site by php or any other command. At least I can get the data how much bandwidth each site is consuming and how much disk space each are using. I will then restrict my web application usage according to this data

Answer (score 0):

For the disk space I would suggest one of two options. (1) enable disk quotas on the /var/www partition - this assumes that the two sites are owned by different accounts. (2) put each site on its own LVM partition with the partition sizes set appropriately. They then could not exceed the disk usage until you increased the partition size.

If you set up a virtual network interface for each site the you could use something like wondershaper to limit bandwidth. Otherwise, I think you're out of luck.

Comment: No, all sites will be owned by same user.

Comment: Is there any way to measure the disk space usage and bandwidth of any particular site by php or any other command. At least I can get the data how much bandwidth each site is consuming and how much disk space each are using. I will then restrict my web application usage according to this data.

Comment: @FutureKing Disk space is easy. To to the htdocs directory for each of the two sites and run `du -hs .`. You can likely get an idea of bandwidth used by analysing your web logs with webalizer. Comes bundled in with many Linux distributions.